# Using integral test on $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2 \ln n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

As stated in the title, I have to use the integral test on

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2 \ln n}$$

to prove that it is convergent but I am having trouble doing that

$$\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{1}^{b}\frac{1}{x^2 \ln x}dx $$

because the only substitution that pops into my mind is this

$$u = \ln {x}$$
$$du = \frac{1}{x} dx$$

which is not a possible solution for this problem.

Comment: @Ralf17 Now you need to adjust the integration limits.

Comment: Do you *have* to use the integral test? Because $\frac{1}{x^2 \ln x} < \frac{1}{x^2}$ for big $x$ (note that this also settles the integral test).

Comment: edited it again, it's 2 actually.

Comment: @ Najib yes that was the instruction, I know this is very easy if I use other tests

Comment: Instead you can prove that the integral is bounded for all $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and you have the convergence.

Comment: Is the function possible to integrate? That's the part where I got stuck. I can't imagine the substitution using integration by parts. This is the first I came across this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\forall x\in [3, \infty[\left(1\leq \log(x)\right)\implies \forall x\in [3, \infty[\left(\dfrac{1}{\log(x)}\leq 1 \right)\implies \ldots$

**Further hint:** $\displaystyle \int \limits _2^\infty\dfrac{1}{x^2\log(x)}\mathrm dx=\int \limits _2^3\dfrac{1}{x^2\log(x)}\mathrm dx+\int \limits _3^\infty\dfrac{1}{x^2\log(x)}\mathrm dx$.

Comment: How did you integrate $\frac{1}{x^2 \ln x}$

Comment: @Ralf17 I did not integrate it. You don't need to integrate it. The title of your question suggests you know about the integral test. That's what I'm hinting at.

Comment: So the integral test can be done without integrating the function defined in the series. I'm reading Stewart(as reference) to solve this problem.

Comment: @Ralf17 You only need to make sure the integral converges. My comment above wasn't good, the convergence of the integral, that is what I'm hinting at.

Comment: I'm trying to analyze your hints.

Comment: If you post your version of the integral test, I'll be able to help you better.

Comment: Ok, but I think I might take quite some time.

Comment: Hey Git, I already have an answer.

Comment: @Ralf17 It was already pointed out to you that your derivatives are wrong in your answer. But I think I finally understood why you don't understand my answer. My answer is hinting at proving why the integral $\displaystyle \int \limits _2^\infty\dfrac{1}{x^2\log(x)}\mathrm dx$ converges.

Comment: So if I have prove using the facts that you gave that $$\lim_{b\to\infty} {(something that converges/upper bound of the integral)}$$ I would be able to point out the series converges?

Comment: @Ralf17 I can't figure out your comment. Here's the general idea (ignoring some hypothesis): $\sum (f(n))\text{ converges}\iff \int \limits ^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx\text{ converges}$ and $\left[f\leq g\land \int \limits ^\infty g(x)\mathrm dx\text{ converges}\right]\implies \int \limits ^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx\text{ converges}$.

Answer (score 2):

From Wolfram, $$\int\frac{1}{x^2 \ln x}dx=E_i(-\ln(x)),$$ where $E_i$ stands for the exponential integral.

Your change of variable is the right one and there is no better closed form.